# Error 401 with LinkedIn API POST requests

Tags: php, http, cakephp, authentication

When try to **POST** a status update to LinkedIn, I got **401 Unauthorized** error. I change **Live Status** in my LinkedIn app to **Live** but the problem's still there. I tried http://simplelinkedin.fiftymission.net/demo/ but I still get 401 error... Everything is fine with **GET** requests (get user profile data,...).

Here is request data:

```
POST /v1/people/~/shares HTTP/1.1
Host: api.linkedin.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: CakePHP
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
x-li-format: json
Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_consumer_key="2z82i0j5ahjb",oauth_token="2de47758-86e1-4684-afd3-f55a56051d2d",oauth_nonce="03aae214a19e83fe2757e8061a4b1468",oauth_timestamp="1326363432",oauth_signature="WNbKgq1FnkIgIALI%2FMfVnBHLgTg%3D"
Content-Length: 131

{"comment":"I am tesing CakePHP","content":{"title":"","submitted-url":"","submitted-image-url":""},"visibility":{"code":"anyone"}}
```

And here is response data:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Date: Thu, 12 Jan 2012 10:17:12 GMT
Vary: *
x-li-format: json
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 230

{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "[unauthorized]. OAU:2z82i0j5ahjb|2de47758-86e1-4684-afd3-f55a56051d2d|*01|*01:1326363432:WNbKgq1FnkIgIALI/MfVnBHLgTg=",
  "requestId": "5XSUW613R2",
  "status": 401,
  "timestamp": 1326363433324
}
```

Can anybody help me to debug this to get it solved? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem! The **Content-Type** MUST be **application/json** in order to work! I thought **x-li-format: json** is enough but it is NOT.